# Mapgraphics library on github. C++/Qt/OpenStreetMap

Tags: c++, qt, openstreetmap

I have a question regarding this library: https://github.com/raptorswing/MapGraphics. Contact the maker did not work, so I hope for help here, can someone faced with this same problem.

How do I add an object to my map in this library? Tried to do here is so:

```
    MapGraphicsScene *scene = new MapGraphicsScene();
    MapGraphicsView *view = new MapGraphicsView(scene);

    LineObject line(Position(92.860984, 56.006355), Position(92, 56), 10);
    QPainter linePainter;
    QColor red(255, 0, 0);
    linePainter.setPen(red);
    QStyleOptionGraphicsItem itm;
    line.paint(&linePainter, &itm, view);

    QSharedPointer<OSMTileSource> osmTiles(new OSMTileSource(OSMTileSource::OSMTiles), &QObject::deleteLater);
    QSharedPointer<CompositeTileSource> composite(new CompositeTileSource(), &QObject::deleteLater);
    composite->addSourceBottom(osmTiles);
    view->setTileSource(composite);
```

But it gave no results. Can you help me? :(

Comment: What are the error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to do the following:

```
MapGraphicsObject *line = new LineObject(Position(92.860984, 56.006355), Position(92, 56), 10);
view->scene().addObject(line);
```

This should be done with any type of object.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the relevant bit of code isn't in your snippet, but I wonder if it's http vs https access?  When you try and download a tile such as [this http one](http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/9/253/166.png) it'll now redirect to https.  This caught out a number of clients (to my knowledge Java-based and Flash-based ones).

The [github project](https://github.com/raptorswing/MapGraphics) says "It is a Qt map widget that can use tiles from MapQuest, Openstreetmap, or a custom source you define" which suggests it's actually quite old, since Mapquest haven't had their own map tiles for a very long time.  Try using a custom source and define https access to OSM tiles.

Comment: https://github.com/raptorswing/MapGraphics/issues/21 has now been fixed, so I'd suggest that you get the latest version and try again.